# Did a starving Great Wall guard let enemies through?

Tags: china

I watched a documentary once about the Great Wall of China. In it, it claimed that a soldier or guard at the time of one of the dynasties let an enemy force through in exchange for food because he was starving due to not being paid enough.  I am writing a white paper on physical security and wanted to reference this as a fact but am finding it hard to search for this because of all the Chinese restaurants called Great Wall and most of what I find on protecting the wall is about protecting it from deterioration in modern times.

Can someone confirm this as fact with more details to help me search for references (ie. Which dynasty, which enemy, etc).

Thanks.

Comment: I'd be rather sceptical.

Comment: Google seems to return some religious "parables" that may be related including a quote from Harry Emerson Fosdick here: http://ministry127.com/resources/illustration/breaching-the-great-wall-of-china. Another suggests a date of 1644 during the Ming dynasty with the Manchus as the invaders: http://odb.org/2009/01/31/a-breach-in-the-wall/. This site claims Ghengis Kahn managed to bribe a sentry to gain access through the wall in the 13th century: http://factsanddetails.com/china/cat2/sub1/item27.html. None appear to offer detailed references however.

Comment: Great idea - everyone's starving, so let in more hungry mouths that will eat still more food. Never mind whatever other tribulations the invaders bring.

Comment: I suggest that you learn about the advanced search capabilities of Google.

Comment: So reference it as apocryphal. You are trying to make a point, not teach a history lesson, right?